# How can I tell what is taking my request so long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, logging, analysis

So here's the final line of my request:

```
Completed in 9209ms (View: 358, DB: 1582)
```

So I need to figure out what's holding up the request.  This request can get to be upwards of a minute, so I really need to figure this one out.  If the DB and View take 1.9 seconds, then that means there's 7.2 seconds that are unaccounted for in the log.  How can I further analyze other parts of the code?  It would be great to know if, say, there was a single callback that's largely responsible for the delay.

Comment: Are you seeing those numbers in production or development?

Comment: @mosch Both development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Generally code that isn't in the DB or the view is in the controller (or it could be in the logic part of the model). The biggest culprits I've had problems with are loops within loops, or gratuitous use of `:include => {...stuff...}`

Comment: Wouldn't `:include` usage fall under DB, and thus be part of the `DB: 1582`?

Comment: The `DB:` time only includes the time that your database process was running. It doesn't include the processing Rails does to instantiate objects and set up associations. If you have a deeply nested `:include` this can become incredibly significant

Answer (score 0):

Are you materializing a lot of records from the database?  Query time might not be much, but if, say, I selected 10,000 records from the database using a very simple and fast query, I'd still expect my page load time to be high, since it would spend a considerable amount of time hydrating the large recordset.

I'd suggest running some profiling tests (`rake test:profile`).  These should give you an indication of where most of the time is being spent.  You'll probably find it's just one or two method calls that are being invoked with excessive frequency.